# Submit the form and debugging in Django

Tags: python, html, django, list, model

I want to create a form so that the user can register a product.
However, the form is created but not submit.
What is the reason?

And when selecting the status, instead of the old version or the new version, n and o are recorded on the product page.
Why?

views.py:

```
# create list
    @login_required(login_url="login")
    def create_list(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            item = List()
            item.user = request.user.username
            item.title = request.POST["create_list_title"]
            item.category = request.POST["category"]
            item.status = request.POST["status"]
            item.description = request.POST["create_list_description"]
            item.first_bid = request.POST["create_list_initial_bid"]
            item.image_url = request.POST["img_url"]
            item.save()
            return redirect("index")
        return render(request, "auctions/create_list.html")`
```

create_list.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
    
    {% block body %}
        <h2 id = "h2">Create List</h2>
        <div>
            <form  method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <a id ="h4">Title :    <input  required placeholder="Title" autofocus type="text" name="create_title"/>
                <a id = "h4">Category : <input required placeholder="Category" type="text" name="category"/></a>
                <a id = "h4">Description : <textarea placeholder="Add Description" required type="text" name="create_desc"></textarea></a>
                <a id = "h4">Starting bid : <input required placeholder="Starting bid" type="number" name="create_initial_bid"/></a>
                <a id = "h4">Status : <input required placeholder="Status" type="text" name="status"/></a>
                
                <form  action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label id="h4" for="fileUpload">Upload Image:</label>
                    <input id="h4" type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload">
                </form><br>
    
                <a id = "h4">Image_url :<input placeholder="Image URL" type="text" name="img_url"/></a><br>
    
                <button id = "button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>   
        </div>
          
    {% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
class List(models.Model):
        choice = (
            ("n", "new vertion"),
            ("o", "old vertion")
        )
        user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        description = models.TextField()  
        category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
        first_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)   
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
        image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
        active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

I want to create a form so that the user can register a product. However, the form is created but not submit. What is the reason?

Answer 1) : -

Change action url to your post save url.

```
<form  action="upload.php"
```

To

```
<form  action="your form submit url"
```

2. For your 2nd question,
   And when selecting the status, instead of the old version or the new version, n and o are recorded on the product page. Why?

Answer 2) : -

```
choice = (
            ("n", "new vertion"),
            ("o", "old vertion")
        )
```

You can change that to look like below, if you like.
Which will save "new vertion" and "old vertion" to the DB as you wanted.

```
choice = (
            ("new vertion", "new vertion"),
            ("old vertion", "old vertion")
        )
```

In django n, o is saved to database, while "new vertion" and "old vertion" shown in UI for users to select.
You can change these as you like, To suite your needs. That's the way django work..

Comment: If the answer answers your questions mark the answer as accepted.